# How can ensure that only two people can join a call in Agora.io?

Tags: dart, agora.io

I am using the quickstart example from [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine) but I noticed that anyone can join the channel call once they get into the screen where I put the agora example. I've tested it on three devices and they all were active at the same video call. How can I specify it for only two persons?

There isn't a way to control the user_id within the provided method that Agora provides.

```dart
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_engine.dart';
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_local_view.dart' as RtcLocalView;
import 'package:agora_rtc_engine/rtc_remote_view.dart' as RtcRemoteView;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

const appId = "547f11b9a1824d6edfgd9933bbfbb7d35a0f";
const token = "006547f11b9a1824d6e99fd33bbfbb7d35a0fIADLt8eND8MBXheUrYFISkxYBh8YlXme/t2jt26BjBJBhWQbs7gAfdAAAAEAfdCf/BrplexuYgEAAQCV7G5i";
const channel = "myApp";
        
   
class MyAppp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyApppState createState() => _MyApppState();
}
    
class _MyApppState extends State<MyAppp> {

  int? remoteUid;
  bool localUserJoined = false;
   
  late RtcEngine engine;
    
    
  @override
  void dispose() {
    engine.destroy();
    super.dispose();
  }
    
    
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

    
  Future<void> initAgora() async {
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();
    engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);    
    await engine.enableVideo();
    
    engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {              
          print("local user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            localUserJoined = true;
          });
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {          
          print("remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            remoteUid = uid;
          });
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {              
          print("remote user $uid left channel");
          setState(() {
            remoteUid = null;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
    
    await engine.joinChannel(token, channel, null,0);
    //  await engine.joinChannelWithUserAccount(token, channel, 'kjlkjljkohklkkkhlk');
    
  }
    
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Video Call'),
      ),
      body:
      Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _remoteVideo(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              child: Center(
                child: localUserJoined
                    ? const RtcLocalView.SurfaceView()
                    : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
    
  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {  
    if (remoteUid != null) {
      return RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
        uid: remoteUid!,
        channelId: channel,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'Please wait for remote user to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a support for 1-1 calling by [Agora](https://docs.agora.io/en/help/integration-issues/profile_difference) in the latest SDKs where you can use **setChannelProfile()** to set to the value **CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION**

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. The Agora SDK doesn't inherently limit the number of users in a call; that's up to your application's logic to enforce.

That being said, you can limit access in a number of ways. The most secure method is to [use token-based authentication](https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/authentication-workflow?platform=flutter). Token-based authentication ensures that only users with valid tokens can join a channel. This approach limits the call to specific users and adds security by preventing unauthorized access.

First, make sure your project has security features enabled, you can do this by logging into [the Agora console](https://console.agora.io/).

You'll need a server that generates tokens. Agora provides [an example token server implementation](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service) that you can use as a starting point and customize depending on your application logic.

Before a user joins a channel, your app logic should request a token from your token server. The server should only issue tokens to the specific users that should be able to join the call.

Once your client device has the token they can join the channel using the token. Any attempt to join without a valid token will be denied by Agora's system.

Answer (score -1):

You can use different channel name to add people in a call